# How to well deal with the git diff with compatible to visual-line-mode?

Tags: magit, git

I typeset my manuscript in org-mode with `visual-line-mode` turned on. Physically one of my paragraphs is just a line which is soft-wrapped.

In this case, when I tried to git diff (magit) to see what I have changed, all of this line (paragraph) is marked to be changed. I could not find out which part of this paragraph have been changed simply.

I think there should be some solutions regrading this issue, but I could not find any answer from website. Can anyone share your good solution?

Comment: The git command I use to deal with this is `git diff --color-words`.  I don't know how to get magit to use that option.

Comment: @erikstokes: magit currently can't use it, but see `magit-diff-refine-hunk` for something similar.

Comment: @npostavs Your comment is very useful. So if that is okay, i would like to ask you to answer this question for other's convenience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can customize/set [`magit-diff-refine-hunk`](http://magit.vc/manual/magit/Diff-options.html#index-magit_002ddiff_002drefine_002dhunk) to highlight word changes. `magit-diff-toggle-refine-hunk`, bound to `D t`, can be used to change it on the fly.

```
magit-diff-refine-hunk is a variable defined in `magit-diff.el'.

Whether to show word-granularity differences within diff hunks.

nil    never show fine differences.
t      show fine differences for the selected diff hunk only.
`all'  show fine differences for all displayed diff hunks.
```

Comment: Also `M-x magit-diff-toggle-refine-hunk` bound to `D t` (i.e. via `magit-diff-refresh-popup`) in Magit 2.